# Include a Adobe Flash File Format (.swf) in Drupal 7 Custom Module

Tags: flash, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I had included java script and css files in Drupal 7 custom module using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7). I was wondering how can I include a file with extension (.swf). Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to embed .swf files.

You can create a [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) implementation in your module to dynamically create the flash markup using less code.

in your `.module` file:

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'mymodule_flash'=>array(
            'template' => 'flash', // create a template file to match this name
            'path' => $path,
            'type' => 'theme',
            'variables' => array(
                'path_to_swf' => NULL,
                'width'  => '600',
                'height' => '400',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Then create `flash.tpl.php` file:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="$path_to_flash" 
    width="$width" height="$height"> 

    <param name="movie" value="$path_to_flash" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
</object>
```

Then us it from any module (or any other module) like so:

```
$vars = array();
$vars['path_to_flash'] = "path/to/flash.swf";
$vars['width'] = "800"; // override default value for width
print theme('mymodule_flash', $vars);
```